# The term '' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am pretty new to coding and am having this issue, can't understand how to fix it, I have seen similar questions asked but, I just cant understand the majority of them. I've tried adding
the path several times, have even reinstalled Vscode it just doesn't seem to resolve.

The code I've Written::

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  print("Enter your name");
  var name = stdin.readLineSync();
  print("The name is $name");
}
```

The Error I am Getting is:

```
Jack : The term 'Jack' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, 
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Jack
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Jack:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have tried:

1:Setting the Paths again

2:Reinstall vs code.

Any kind of information will really help, I can't really progress anymore because of this.

Comment: can you post your complete code?

Comment: That is the whole code or am i not understanding some part of it .

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your program? When I write a program with your exact code, it works.

You have written a command line script in Dart and thus need to run it as such. For example, if you saved your program in the file `my_app.dart`, then from the command line you could run `dart my_app.dart` and it'll run your script.

Another way to run it is to create a dart console app and run it using `dart run` as outlined here: https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/get-started. This would be my recommendation and if you follow the guide I think you'll be able to figure it out, but to quickly confirm your code works you can do the first suggestion.

Comment: The first way is how i do it , it still isn't working , ill look into the other way you have mentioned.

Comment: Are you running it directly from the terminal in vs code? Ia it bash?

Comment: well i , run the code and enter the name in the terminal.

Comment: directly in Vscode. i think.

Comment: Your error looks an awful lot like PowerShell, and not bash, which might be the problem

Comment: i got another bud who told me its a terminal error , i don't really understand what it actually means because i am new to all this , how do you think this can be fixed ?

Comment: Your code works and runs as expected on my machine. I have to assume that you're actually hitting an issue with PowerShell, but I don't know enough about PowerShell to give you advice. If you're open to it, I would suggest running it in a bash terminal. I run bash out of vscode, so you should be able to switch your terminal from PowerShell to bash