# the term '...' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet vs code. *quarto*

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, path, quarto

I've been happily rendering quarto documents in VS code using the 'render' button. Then the next day I get the error (ignore the xxxx in place of my username):

```
Uni : The term 'Uni' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the       
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:50
 + cmd /C"quarto preview "c:\Users\xxxx\Dropbox (Uni of Auckland)\Qui ...
 +                                                  ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Uni:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Seems to be a problem with the path or the whitespace and there are many questions on stack referencing the same issue using different software that have not helped me:

- [The term '' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71308119/the-term-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet-function-script-file)
- [The term 'go' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48602324/the-term-go-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet-function-script-file)
- [go : The term 'go' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55873381/go-the-term-go-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet-function-script-f?rq=1)
- [The term 'appcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945542/the-term-appcmd-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet)

It renders just fine if I run the command `quarto render .\example.qmd`. Or if I move the working directory to my Desktop then the render button works again. I cannot change the name of the dropbox because it is institutionally managed.
No idea what changed overnight... I would quite like to get the function of using the render button back.

Any ideas? Thanks Stack community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the double quotes are nested. There's one set of double quotes for the command passed to cmd /C, and another set for the file path.

Try change your default terminal to something other than cmd /C. Here's how you can change your terminal - https://www.shanebart.com/set-default-vscode-terminal/